# Really struggling with Autolayout - 4 buttons arranged 2x2

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, grid-layout, aspect-ratio

I have a fairly simple scene in my Storyboard, but I can't manage to arrange the four orange buttons with Autolayout.

[image: scene with four buttons]

I've been trying to get this right for a week. I've searched online and I must not have the right keywords, because I haven't found anything that applies.

Everything but the orange buttons are behaving correctly for all devices.

The orange buttons should be arranged in a 2x2 grid.

I want the distance between the "Question" label and the first row of buttons to be the same distance between the second row of buttons and the "Home" button.

I want the orange buttons to retain the same aspect ratio, and I want them to grow/shrink as much as possible, but they should remain centered horizontally and vertically between "Question" and "Home" and the left/right edges.

Comment: When you say "grow/shrink as much as possible", do you want some minimum spacing to either the labels or the left or right edges of the main view?

Comment: Yes, there should be appropriate spacing up/down/left/right. But, the elements should grow as much as the spacing will allow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use container views to divide and conquer the layout.

Start with top, middle, and bottom views:

[image: Initial Layout]

The middle view constraints are:

- Center X in container
- Center Y in container
- Aspect ratio 1:1
- Leading/Trailing/Top/Bottom space = 10, 250 priority
- Leading/Trailing/Top/Bottom space >= 10, 1000 priority

This will give you support for both landscape and portrait orientations:

[image]

Now you can add the 4 grid views inside of the middle view:

[image]

The grid views will have equal widths and heights to each other, and set the spacing between the views to taste.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I'm really trying to avoid using container views - it feels too much like container `DIV`s in HTML/CSS and just mucks up the simplicity of the layout. But, I may have to do it anyway, just to get past this obstacle.

My four buttons are not squares, they are rectangles, but I haven't decided what ratio, yet. I think it may end up being 2.545:1 (qatari flag dimensions)

Comment: I did finally do it with various nested views. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can only do so much using the storyboard. You will either have to insert an outlet and manually manage the frame sizes, or you can programmatically use autolayout to mimic your intended behavior. I can help you with the programmatic part if you are open for it.